# Spring boot rest ignore one class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am developing a REST API using spring-boot-starter-data-rest. One class I want to sync with JPA is the User class containing information about users, including who is allowed to access the API.

Unfortunately, having the User and the UserRepository means that my User class is exposed in my API. I was able to remove things like the Id (in the configureRepositoryRestConfiguration function) and usernames and passwords (by adding @JsonIgnore to every variable of my User class).

Unfortunately, users of the API can still ask for the users table (who returns a list with empty users). Although this is not really a problem, I would rather remove the /users endpoint.

Adding @JsonIgnore to the whole User class is not possible.

Comment: What if you just remove the @RepositoryRestResource from the repository interface?

Comment: Never defined @RepositoryRestResource, I did define 

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting repositories is depend on [RepositoryDetectionStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_which_repositories_get_exposed_by_defaults). The **default** strategy is:

> Exposes all public repository interfaces but considers @(Repository)RestResource’s `exported` flag.

According it to disable exporting of your 'repo' you can set `exported` flag to `false` for this repo:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    //...
}
```

Another approach is to change globally the **RepositoryDetectionStrategy** to `ANNOTATED`:

> Only repositories annotated with @(Repository)RestResource are exposed, unless their exported flag is set to false.

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(RepositoryDetectionStrategy.RepositoryDetectionStrategies.ANNOTATED);
        super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
    }
}
```

Then don't apply `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation to repos that doesn't need to be exported.

**UPDATE**

We can also use this application property to setup the strategy:

```
spring.data.rest.detection-strategy=default
```

[Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can hide certain repositories by adding this annotation to your repository: `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)`.

More informations here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.hiding-repositories

Answer (score 0):

There's such thing as [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts).

You can define interface with fields you want and use it as repository's method:

```
@Projection(name = "simpleUser", types = { User.class }) 
interface SimpleUser { 

  String getFirstName(); 

  String getLastName(); 
}
```

Comment: But that's the point of spring-data-rest. It's purpose is to expose a restful API for your repositories, hence it's intended that there are no DTOs. For more info please refer to http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/

Comment: @systemfreund oh, sorry, haven't noticed spring data part